# Persistent Homology with Integer Coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, topological-data-analysis

Does anyone know if persistent homology with integer coefficients are being used anywhere?

From what I understand, Carlsson's persistent module theory (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.116.2471&rep=rep1&type=pdf) works well for field coefficients (only).

Quote: "The correspondence established by Theorem 3.1 suggests the non-existence of simple classifications of persistence modules over a ground ring that is not a field." (pg 7 of the paper)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the relevance of this theorem for your purposes?

Comment: @PeterSaveliev No specific purpose at the moment, just curious about what happens for non-fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a paper "Defining and computing persistent Z-homology in the general case" by Romero et al., arxiv:1403.7086.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.